# Get Exchange Rate From Currency Converter API in C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

Here is my api call:

```
https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=y
```

I wrote a method that accepts to/from parameters for exchange rates and I successfully get back a result. My problem is parsing that result to get the value. Here is what I have thus far:

```
public async Task<string> GetExchangeRate(string from, string to)
{
    //Examples:
    //from = "EUR"
    //to = "USD"
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://free.currencyconverterapi.com");
            var response = await client.GetAsync($"/api/v6/convert?q={from}_{to}&compact=y");
            var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic data = JObject.Parse(stringResult);
            //data = {"EUR_USD":{"val":1.140661}}
            //I want to return 1.140661
            //EUR_USD is dynamic depending on what from/to is
            return data.?????.val;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(httpRequestException.StackTrace);
            return "Error calling API. Please do manual lookup.";
        }
    }
}
```

If my data variable = `{"EUR_USD":{"val":1.140661}}` where `"EUR_USD"` is dynamic (It changes pending on what to/from is) then how do I return 1.140661?

**ANSWER I USED**
Here is the code I used based off of @maccettura comment:

```
var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var dictResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(stringResult);
return dictResult[$"{from}_{to}"]["val"];
```

Comment: Deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @maccettura.

```
var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var dictResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(stringResult);
return dictResult[$"{from}_{to}"]["val"];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're still searching for the solution to get the exchange rates thru an API in C#, you can try this code available here: https://currencyfreaks.com/documentation.html#Latest.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.currencyfreaks.com/latest
    ?apikey=YOUR_APIKEY
    &base=GBP
    &symbols=EUR,USD,PKR,INR");

client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: What namespaces did you reference to get this code to run

Answer (score 0):

As it is parsed with Newtonsoft.JSON, then use [JProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) to read the properties.

```
foreach (JProperty property in data)
{
      Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
      Console.WriteLine(property.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net MVC
1: Get Your Free  API KEY From This Site : Notice : retrieve 50 000 free monthly requests.

```
https://freecurrencyapi.net/
```

2: Use This Code :

```
                var CRFrom = "USD";
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                string getString = client.DownloadString("https://freecurrencyapi.net/api/v2/latest?apikey=API KEY&base_currency=" + CRFrom + "");
                JObject GetData = JObject.Parse(getString);
                string JPY = (string)GetData["data"]["JPY"];
                string CNY = (string)GetData["data"]["CNY"];
                string CHF = (string)GetData["data"]["CHF"];
                string CAD = (string)GetData["data"]["CAD"];
                string MXN = (string)GetData["data"]["MXN"];
                string INR = (string)GetData["data"]["INR"];
                string BRL = (string)GetData["data"]["BRL"];
                string RUB = (string)GetData["data"]["RUB"];
                string KRW = (string)GetData["data"]["KRW"];
                string IDR = (string)GetData["data"]["IDR"];
                string TRY = (string)GetData["data"]["TRY"];
                string SAR = (string)GetData["data"]["SAR"];
                string SEK = (string)GetData["data"]["SEK"];
                string NGN = (string)GetData["data"]["NGN"];
                string PLN = (string)GetData["data"]["PLN"];
                string ARS = (string)GetData["data"]["ARS"];
                string NOK = (string)GetData["data"]["NOK"];
                string TWD = (string)GetData["data"]["TWD"];
                string IRR = (string)GetData["data"]["IRR"];
                string AED = (string)GetData["data"]["AED"];
                string COP = (string)GetData["data"]["COP"];
                string THB = (string)GetData["data"]["THB"];
                string ZAR = (string)GetData["data"]["ZAR"];
                string DKK = (string)GetData["data"]["DKK"];
                string MYR = (string)GetData["data"]["MYR"];
                string SGD = (string)GetData["data"]["SGD"];
                string ILS = (string)GetData["data"]["ILS"];
                string HKD = (string)GetData["data"]["HKD"];
                string EGP = (string)GetData["data"]["EGP"];
                string PHP = (string)GetData["data"]["PHP"];
                string CLP = (string)GetData["data"]["CLP"];
                string PKR = (string)GetData["data"]["PKR"];
                string IQD = (string)GetData["data"]["IQD"];
                string DZD = (string)GetData["data"]["DZD"];
                string KZT = (string)GetData["data"]["KZT"];
                string QAR = (string)GetData["data"]["QAR"];
                string CZK = (string)GetData["data"]["CZK"];
                string PEN = (string)GetData["data"]["PEN"];
                string RON = (string)GetData["data"]["RON"];
                string VND = (string)GetData["data"]["VND"];
                string BDT = (string)GetData["data"]["BDT"];
                string HUF = (string)GetData["data"]["HUF"];
                string UAH = (string)GetData["data"]["UAH"];
                string AOA = (string)GetData["data"]["AOA"];
                string MAD = (string)GetData["data"]["MAD"];
                string OMR = (string)GetData["data"]["OMR"];
                string CUC = (string)GetData["data"]["CUC"];
                string BYR = (string)GetData["data"]["BYR"];
                string AZN = (string)GetData["data"]["AZN"];
                string LKR = (string)GetData["data"]["LKR"];
                string SDG = (string)GetData["data"]["SDG"];
                string SYP = (string)GetData["data"]["SYP"];
                string MMK = (string)GetData["data"]["MMK"];
                string DOP = (string)GetData["data"]["DOP"];
                string UZS = (string)GetData["data"]["UZS"];
                string KES = (string)GetData["data"]["KES"];
                string GTQ = (string)GetData["data"]["GTQ"];
                string URY = (string)GetData["data"]["URY"];
                string HRV = (string)GetData["data"]["HRV"];
                string MOP = (string)GetData["data"]["MOP"];
                string ETB = (string)GetData["data"]["ETB"];
                string CRC = (string)GetData["data"]["CRC"];
                string TZS = (string)GetData["data"]["TZS"];
                string TMT = (string)GetData["data"]["TMT"];
                string TND = (string)GetData["data"]["TND"];
                string PAB = (string)GetData["data"]["PAB"];
                string LBP = (string)GetData["data"]["LBP"];
                string RSD = (string)GetData["data"]["RSD"];
                string LYD = (string)GetData["data"]["LYD"];
                string GHS = (string)GetData["data"]["GHS"];
                string YER = (string)GetData["data"]["YER"];
                string BOB = (string)GetData["data"]["BOB"];
                string BHD = (string)GetData["data"]["BHD"];
                string CDF = (string)GetData["data"]["CDF"];
                string PYG = (string)GetData["data"]["PYG"];
                string UGX = (string)GetData["data"]["UGX"];
                string SVC = (string)GetData["data"]["SVC"];
                string TTD = (string)GetData["data"]["TTD"];
                string AFN = (string)GetData["data"]["AFN"];
                string NPR = (string)GetData["data"]["NPR"];
                string HNL = (string)GetData["data"]["HNL"];
                string BIH = (string)GetData["data"]["BIH"];
                string BND = (string)GetData["data"]["BND"];
                string ISK = (string)GetData["data"]["NOK"];
                string KHR = (string)GetData["data"]["ISK"];
                string GEL = (string)GetData["data"]["GEL"];
                string MZN = (string)GetData["data"]["MZN"];
                string BWP = (string)GetData["data"]["BWP"];
                string PGK = (string)GetData["data"]["PGK"];
                string JMD = (string)GetData["data"]["JMD"];
                string XAF = (string)GetData["data"]["XAF"];
                string NAD = (string)GetData["data"]["NAD"];
                string ALL = (string)GetData["data"]["ALL"];
                string SSP = (string)GetData["data"]["SSP"];
                string MUR = (string)GetData["data"]["MUR"];
                string MNT = (string)GetData["data"]["MNT"];
                string NIO = (string)GetData["data"]["NIO"];
                string LAK = (string)GetData["data"]["LAK"];
                string MKD = (string)GetData["data"]["MKD"];
                string AMD = (string)GetData["data"]["AMD"];
                string MGA = (string)GetData["data"]["MGA"];
                string XPF = (string)GetData["data"]["XPF"];
                string TJS = (string)GetData["data"]["TJS"];
                string HTG = (string)GetData["data"]["HTG"];
                string BSD = (string)GetData["data"]["BSD"];
                string MDL = (string)GetData["data"]["MDL"];
                string RWF = (string)GetData["data"]["RWF"];
                string KGS = (string)GetData["data"]["KGS"];
                string GNF = (string)GetData["data"]["GNF"];
                string SRD = (string)GetData["data"]["SRD"];
                string SLL = (string)GetData["data"]["SLL"];
                string XOF = (string)GetData["data"]["XOF"];
                string MWK = (string)GetData["data"]["MWK"];
                string FJD = (string)GetData["data"]["FJD"];
                string ERN = (string)GetData["data"]["ERN"];
                string SZL = (string)GetData["data"]["SZL"];
                string GYD = (string)GetData["data"]["GYD"];
                string BIF = (string)GetData["data"]["BIF"];
                string KYD = (string)GetData["data"]["KYD"];
                string MVR = (string)GetData["data"]["MVR"];
                string LSL = (string)GetData["data"]["LSL"];
                string LRD = (string)GetData["data"]["LRD"];
                string CVE = (string)GetData["data"]["CVE"];
                string DJF = (string)GetData["data"]["DJF"];
                string SCR = (string)GetData["data"]["SCR"];
                string SOS = (string)GetData["data"]["SOS"];
                string GMD = (string)GetData["data"]["GMD"];
                string KMF = (string)GetData["data"]["KMF"];
                string STD = (string)GetData["data"]["STD"];
                string XRP = (string)GetData["data"]["XRP"];
                string AUD = (string)GetData["data"]["AUD"];
                string BGN = (string)GetData["data"]["BGN"];
                string BTC = (string)GetData["data"]["BTC"];
                string JOD = (string)GetData["data"]["JOD"];
                string GBP = (string)GetData["data"]["GBP"];
                string ETH = (string)GetData["data"]["ETH"];
                string EUR = (string)GetData["data"]["EUR"];
                string LTC = (string)GetData["data"]["LTC"];
                string NZD = (string)GetData["data"]["NZD"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Just in case I am adding this solution to here as another way to access through JValue:

```
   return ((JValue)((JProperty)((JContainer)((JContainer)((JContainer)data).First).First).First).Value).Value.ToString();
```

I would prefer @maccettura 's answer as it is more readable code.